# How to hide the Sign in button from Google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google maps (v3) now loads with a "Sign in" button at the top-right corner of the canvas. How to hide this button?

[image: Google maps]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set "signed_in=false" in the API include (or remove it).

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false"></script>
```

See [the documentation on signed in maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin) for more details.

Comment: Thats the problem – I have copied the asynchronous loading example from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial which includes the `signed_in=true` parameter.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas and geocodezip, thank you so much for the question and answer! I've been looking for it everywhere.