# Removing sign in link from google map

Tags: google-maps

I want to remove a signin link from google map, the code which is displaying map is :

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3770.8179999384315!2d72.82549100000001!3d19.071738!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3be7c97259c1c731%3A0xea3269aa63a17fc0!2sLe+Sutra!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1414997099454" width="450" height="285" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you have control over that with the [embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide).  You can do it with the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Related question: [How to hide the Sign in button from Google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125321/how-to-hide-the-sign-in-button-from-google-maps)